# CodeIgniter : Session does not work in google Chrome

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

The browser has succesfully got a cookie once (how? when? i really can't tell. I just can tell that at a certain time, I realized that my website wasn't working anymore in chrome). Now chrome keeps showing : "This site has no cookies" in the developpment tool.

It works fine in explorer / firefox / safari, etc...

Since CI session library use cookies and all my pages use the session library, I really need to fix this.

Here is my config (database table exists, works, and normally cookie is encrypted)

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = '[mydomain]sessions';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 60*60*24*7; // one week
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = '[mydomain]sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Here is cookie config

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "[mydomain.com]";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

When user logs in, it does :

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('user', array('id' => $logged_in_user_id));
$row = $query->row();
$this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $row->user_id);
redirect(base_url(), 'location');
```

When user logs out, it does :

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
redirect(base_url(), 'location');
```

This is simple and i guess this is the way it should be done? any idea why it does not work in chrome but works perfectly in firefox / explorer / safari?

Comment: you have set sess_use_database to true so your session is maintained through database not by cookies

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a dot to this line:

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = ".[mydomain.com]";
```

My configuration is the same and it works with Google Chrome, but I have these ones different:

```
$config['sess_expiration']      = 86400;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
```

I hope it works :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion jonaypelluz. I tryed and it did not work.  I left cookie_domain blank and now it works. The browser has set the domain name properly. It looks like it should be handled by the browser...?

Answer (score 1):

Add `ob_start()` on top of session library.

```
ob_start();
$this->load->library('Session');
```

And add `ob_clean()` in your session destroying part

```
$this->load->driver('cache');
$this->session->sess_destroy();
$this->cache->clean();
ob_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you (well in the past I have) resolve(d) it by extending the session expiry but I see  yours is already set to one week. Try making it shorter? 
For example:

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 8600;
```

Alternatively, you could try turning off encrypt cookie as I've just read on the CI forums someone else has resolved the issue through this method:

```
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
```

Hope I helped. Let me know how it goes for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Config And just replace this if you are using on local system :

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = 'your_prefix';
$config['cookie_domain']    = 'localhost';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/folder_name/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

Or if you are using it on server just replace it  like :

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = 'localhost';
to
$config['cookie_domain']    = '.localhost';
```

hopefully it will help you.